# Get interaction's reponse message object discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, discord, discord.js

Si I have this really simple command :

```js
let row = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(...) // The .. is too long so i'll just remove it for this question
int.reply({ content : 'pong', components : [row]})
```

It works perfectly. It sends the message with the components and works just fine.
The problem is now I want to listen to the buttons.
On a message, I can do

```js
message.reply({ content : 'ok', components : [row]})
.then(msg =>{
  let collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType : 'BUTTON', time : 10e5 })
  // Collector thingys

})
.catch(console.error)
```

That also works perfectly, I can listen to the messages and do something :D Now the problem is that when replying to the message, the promise returns `undefined`

```js
int.reply('Replied to your message')
```

How to get the reply and be able to listen to it's buttons ? :/

**EDIT :**
I actually found it.
I just had to add { fetchReply : true } when sending an interaction response
For example:

```js
const reply = await interaction.reply({ content : 'Test !', components : [row], fetchReply : true})

// Do something with "reply"..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found it. I just had to add `{ fetchReply : true }` as an additionnal option when sending an interaction response.
For example:

```
// replymsg will be undefined
let replymsg = await interaction.reply({ content : 'Yes !' })
// replymsg will be the reply of the interaction
let replymsg = await interaction.reply({ content : 'Yes !', fetchReply: true })
```

Simply replaced the first line with the second

Answer (score 1):

So I would build it like this:

```js
const row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
        .setCustomId('ButtonIdChangeThis')
        .setLabel('WhatButtonSaysChangeThis')
        .setStyle('SUCCESS')
// can use ‘SUCCESS’ for green, ‘DANGER’ for red, ‘PRIMARY’ for blurple, ‘SECONDARY’ for grey
    )
```

Then you would collect it under your `.on(“interactionCreate”)` event using this code:

```js
client.on(“interactionCreate”, async interaction => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        const buttonID = interaction.customId
        if (buttonID === 'ButtonIdChangeThis') {
//put what button does here
    }
})
```

Then if anyone clicks it (even between reboots) the button click is listened to and responded to.